# Semantic Versioning in Artifactory Generic Repositories: Range Query

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I would like to know if the generic repositories in JFrog Artifactory have support for something similar as NodeJS's `~` and `^` operator in the `package.json`.

Let say I am uploading the following artifacts to a generic repository:

- foo-1.0.0      # stable release for 1.0 series
- foo-1.0.1      # first bug fix release for 1.0 series
- foo-1.1.0      # stable release for 1.1 series
- foo-1.1.1      # first bug fix release for 1.1 series

Is there some REST API or AQL query that I can use to specify a particular version based on a query, e.g.: `~1.0.0` would get me `1.0.1` and if later I upload `1.0.2` it would give me `1.0.2`?

See [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) for a description about NodeJS `~` and `^` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in support for such semver operators in AQL or the REST API.
You can get the latest version of an artifact in a generic repository, you can use the [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties) API method (which requires annotating the artifacts with a version property).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking forward to maybe see support for that in the future.